# Is it possible to call an flow.action inside jsp:include tag?

Tags: java, jsp, tags, action, jsp-tags

I have a problem with an application, did not made for me.
In a jsp file there are a call to a flow.action it within a tag jsp:include

It does not work, is this possible?

```
    <div>
        <jsp:include page="/app/exmpl/lnk/flow.action?expID=${expID}&screenID=escID"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `/app/exmpl/lnk/flow.action` be a url that's mapped to some servlet?